# Calling asynchronous function but returning result synchronously

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

I want to construct a function that creates and returns an `Observable`. Depending on the parameters this function receives it should either create the `Observable` and return it directly or (in a special case) call another asynchronous function before returning the `Observable`.

Abstract example:

```
async function doSomethingAsync(){
    return 'success';
}

function returnObservable(specialCase: boolean): Observable<any>
    const observable = new Observable(
        observer =>
            observer.next(1)
        }
    );

    if(specialCase) {
        doSomethingAsync().then(
            then => {
                // this does not work, of course, but that's what I would like to be able to do
                return observable;
            }
        )       
    } else {
        return observable;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that appearently I cannot call an asynchronous function and then return the `Observable`. I could make this whole `returnObservable` function asynchronous and just `await` the `doSomethingAsync` but then the `returnObservable` function would return a `Promise` returning an `Observable` - and that's not what I want. The consumer of this function should receive the Observable directly.

I hope I could make my problem clear. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Once your code became asynchronous - the rest would be asynchronous too, it's viral.

Comment: @zerkms - Very well put. But since the OP is returning an asynchronous kind of construct (and `Observable`), there's hope. :-)

Comment: @zerkms "It's viral"... lol.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I reused it from the GPL, which is called a "viral license" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_license /cc briosheje

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to solve this problem?

Because you're returning an `Observable`, there may be.

It's impossible to have `returnObservable` block synchronously until an `async` function returns. **But**, you can have it return an `Observable` that (optionally) won't emit any events until the async function completes. You could even have it not even call the async function until/unless something subscribes to it.

Something vaguely like:

```
function returnObservable(specialCase: boolean): Observable<any>
    const promise = specialCase ? doSomethingAsync() : Promise.resolve();
    const observable = new Observable(
        observer => {
            promise
            .then(() => {
                observer.next(1);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // deal with the error
            });
        }
    );

    return observable;
}
```

(You might even be able to use [`fromPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise). I'm not strong enough on Rx.js to be sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Transform the promise into an observable:

```
async function doSomethingAsync(){
    return 'success';
}

function returnObservable(specialCase: boolean): Observable<any>
    const observable = new Observable(
        observer =>
            observer.next(1)
        }
    );

    if(specialCase) {
        return Observable.from(doSomethingAsync().then(
            then => {
                // this does not work, of course, but that's what I would like to be able to do
                return observable;
            }
        ));
    }
    return observable;
}
```

Comment: This will return an Observable that emits an Observable when `specialCase == true`. The code should be `return from(doSomethingAsync()).pipe(switchMap(val => observable));`

Comment: Exactly, the consumer should not have to handle another Observable. @fridoo 's solution is what I wanted.